# jQuery toggle between 2 functions inside a click event

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jQuery, and I can't seem to make this work.

I have a hamburguer button toggler, which when clicked, it should open a menu panel. At the same time, it should call a function to prevent scroll of the document.

I have 2 functions, one to disable the document scroll, other to enable it back:

```
function disableScroll(){...}
function enableScroll(){...}
```

And here I have the toggler icon click event:

```
$("#main-nav-toggler").click(function() {
        $("#main-nav-menu").toggleClass("menu-show");
        disableScroll();
});
```

The problem is, I don't know how to toggle between the 2 scroll functions within the toggler click event. I only know how to call one function, I don't know how to toggle between the 2 on click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `hasClass()` function to check which function you need to call.

```js
$("#main-nav-toggler").click(function() {
        $("#main-nav-menu").toggleClass("menu-show");
        $("#main-nav-menu").hasClass("menu-show") ? disableScroll() : enableScroll();
});

function disableScroll(){
  console.log("disable scroll");
}
function enableScroll(){
  console.log("enable scroll");
}
```

```css
#main-nav-menu {
  display: none;
}

#main-nav-menu.menu-show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-nav-toggler">toggler
</div>
<div id="main-nav-menu">menu
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I just started to learn js and jQuery, so I need to study it more, I didn't knew about the hasClass(). Thank you very much mate!

Answer (score 2):

You can check if main-nav-menu has a class of .menu-show

```
$("#main-nav-toggler").click(function() {
    $("#main-nav-menu").toggleClass("menu-show");
    if($("#main-nav-toggler").hasClass("menu-show")){
        disableScroll();
    } else{
        enableScroll()
    }
 });
```

Jquery hasClass() documentation: https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't knew about hasClass yet, just started learning jQuery.